# Xcode - Position of Elements Different than in XIB

Tags: xcode, position, xib

I'm having a problem where I align UI elements in my xib file in XCode and then when I run my app in the simulator they appear in a difference position, as shown in below screenshots.

Xcode - table view and text view bottoms align:

[image]

Simulator - table view and text view bottoms no longer align:

[image]

Has anyone else had this problem?

Is the table view compensating for the tab bar at the bottom but the textbox is not?

Comment: So is your problem that the tab bar is not appearing or is it that the "Notes..." view isn't appearing directly to the right of... umm... buttons in a table?  (p.s. ahh, the magic of iOS 6 and Auto Layout)

Comment: My problem is I'm expecting the bottom of the textbox to align with the bottom of the table view to the left, as it does in Xcode but it is going further down.

Comment: The images you've attached in this question really don't make the problem clear, but I'm guessing that you need to add some constraints for your text box to make sure the bottom edge of your textbox is *pinned* to the superview.

Comment: The first image is the view in Xcode - the bottoms of the table view on the left and the textbox on the right align. The second image is from the simulator, where the two no longer align - the textbox goes further down and behind the tabstrip.